# Self-contained React Native app possible?

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I built a react-native app for Windows (https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows). The app runs fine on my development machine, but if I copy the EXE (and DLL dependencies) to another machine and run, I get the error message

> Unable to Download the JS bundle. Did you forget to start the
>   development server or connect your device?

Is there a way to build a **self-contained** app that does not depend on a "development server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**React Native Windows Environment Setup (with Typescript)**

1. Download and Install Visual Studio 2017 [Download Link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
2. Download and Install Visual Studio Code [Download Link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win)
3. Download and Install NodeJS [Download Link](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)
4. Install React Native CLI

   `npm i -g react-native-cli`
5. Install TypeScript

   `npm i -g typescript`
6. Create your project

   `react-native init --version="0.55.0-rc.0" MyApp --template typescript && node MyApp/setup.js`
7. Change project directory MyApp

   `cd MyApp`
8. Install the React Native Windows CLI Plugin

   `npm i --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows`
9. Run the Windows initialization command

   `react-native windows --windowsVersion 0.55.0-rc.0`
10. Open project MyApp.sln file in Visual Studio
11. Follow the prompts to install the `Windows 10 SDK v. 10.0.14393.0`
12. If prompted, select Developer Mode in the Settings window under "Use developer features" and approve the Certificate Installation request. Enable "Developer mode" to allow the custom application to run
13. Install windows build tools (run in Windows Power Shell)

    `npm i -g --production windows-build-tools`
14. Run your application

    `react-native run-windows`
15. Prompt Windows PowerShell Installing Certificate: Enter Y to install
16. Prompt window: Allow Access to windows firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle your JS code using

```
react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.windows.js
--bundle-output windows\myapp\ReactAssets\index.windows.bundle
--assets-dest windows\myapp\ReactAssets
--dev false
```

If you want to upload to store then you can follow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package

Comment: Thank you, Ankit. This created a bundle file windows\myapp\ReactAssets\index.windows.bundle. What do I do with this bundle? I thought I could build an EXE that I could run on a non-development computer.

Comment: Hi @George I have the same question. I am successfully able to generate the bundle. Could you please help me with steps on how to generate release build .exe. I tried following - store > create Package > release - x86,x64 build. but when I run it tries to fetch bundle